# multipart/form-data request pass BLOB files

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to pass BLOB files to JIRA. How I can do that? I tried:

```
DECLARE
    l_start TIMESTAMP;
    l_duration NUMERIC;

    l_result VARCHAR2(32767);  
    p_array APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

    v_login VARCHAR2(100);
    v_password VARCHAR2(100);

    f_body_blob BLOB;
    f_response CLOB;

    f_body_clob CLOB;

BEGIN  
    v_login := 'user';
    v_password := 'psw';

    SELECT PHOTO INTO f_body_blob FROM LEAN5S_PHOTO WHERE ID = 189;

    apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete;
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'multipart/form-data';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'X-Atlassian-Token';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'no-check';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).name := 'file';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).value := 'hand-sanitizer.png';

    l_start := systimestamp;
    f_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'http://site/rest/api/2/issue/key/attachments',  
                                                     p_http_method => 'POST',
                                                     p_body_blob => f_body_blob,
                                                     p_username => v_login,
                                                     p_password => v_password
    );
    l_duration := round(extract(second from systimestamp - l_start) * 1000);

    dbms_output.put_line(apex_web_service.g_status_code || ' ' || f_response);
END;
```

But I'm getting request error (500) and file is doesn't uploads:

> 500 500org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException:
> the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was
> foundjava.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was
> rejected because no multipart boundary was found

My colleague was tried another variant:

```
DECLARE
  p_url          VARCHAR2(255) := 'http://site/rest/api/2/issue/key/attachments';
  utl_req        utl_http.req;
  utl_resp       utl_http.resp;
  req_length     BINARY_INTEGER;
  response_body  VARCHAR2(32767);
  p_request_body clob;
  l_newline      VARCHAR2(50) := chr(13) || chr(10);
  lco_boundary CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'AaB03x';
  buffer raw(32767);
  amount number(15) := 32767;
  offset number(15) := 1;

  l_attachment blob;
  l_file_name  VARCHAR2(255);
  l_mime_type  VARCHAR2(255);
  
  l_response_header_name varchar2(256);
  l_response_header_value varchar2(1024);
  l_response_body varchar2(32767);

  lang_context integer;
  warning      varchar2(1000);
  blb          blob;

  tmp_blob blob default EMPTY_BLOB();

  dest_offset integer := 1;
  src_offset  integer := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT PHOTO, FILENAME, MIMETYPE
        INTO l_attachment, l_file_name, l_mime_type
        FROM LEAN5S_PHOTO
        WHERE ID = 156;

  p_request_body := l_newline || '--' || lco_boundary || l_newline ||
                    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' ||
                    l_file_name || '"' || l_newline || 'Content-Type: ' ||
                    l_mime_type || l_newline ||
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' || l_newline ||
                    l_newline ||
                    apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(l_attachment) ||
                    l_newline || '--' || lco_boundary || '--';

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(blb, FALSE);
  dest_offset  := 1;
  src_offset   := 1;
  lang_context := 0;
  dbms_lob.converttoblob(blb,
                         p_request_body,
                         dbms_lob.getlength(p_request_body),
                         dest_offset,
                         src_offset,
                         0,
                         lang_context,
                         warning);
  dbms_lob.append(blb, l_attachment);
  req_length := dbms_lob.getlength(blb);

  utl_req := utl_http.begin_request(url          => p_url,
                                    method       => 'POST',
                                    http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_authentication(utl_req, 'user', 'psw', 'Basic');                                  
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'X-Atlassian-Token', 'no-check');
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req,
                      'Content-Type',
                      'multipart/form-data; boundary="' || lco_boundary || '"');
  dbms_output.put_line(req_length);

  IF req_length <= 32767 THEN
    utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'Content-Length', req_length);
    utl_http.write_raw(utl_req, blb);
  ELSIF req_length > 32767 THEN
    utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    WHILE (offset < req_length) LOOP
      dbms_lob.read(blb, amount, offset, buffer);
      utl_http.write_raw(utl_req, buffer);
      offset := offset + amount;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  utl_resp := utl_http.get_response(utl_req);
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Response> Status Code: ' || utl_resp.status_code);
  
  for i in 1 .. utl_http.get_header_count(utl_resp) loop
    utl_http.get_header(utl_resp, i, l_response_header_name, l_response_header_value);
    dbms_output.put_line('Response> ' || l_response_header_name || ': ' || l_response_header_value);
  end loop;

  utl_http.read_text(utl_resp, l_response_body, 32767);
  
  --utl_http.read_raw(utl_resp, response_body, 32767);
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Response body>');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_response_body);
  
  utl_http.end_response(utl_resp);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
    utl_http.END_RESPONSE(utl_resp);
  
END;
```

This variant is working, but file in JIRA is corrupted.

EDIT: Somethink with encoding. I have tried to send .txt file and in JIRA, file content is in Base64 format.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you been able to find solution for this ?